# getting following error while deploying using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler

I did cap deploy, I'm getting following error,

```
* executing "cd /home/deployer/apps/nthat1/releases/20130911190337 && bundle install --gemfile /home/deployer/apps/nthat1/releases/20130911190337/Gemfile --path /home/deployer/apps/nthat1/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
  servers: ["192.241.225.72"]
  [192.241.225.72] executing command
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/psych-1.3.4/lib/psych.rb:96: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] 
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/psych-1.3.4/lib/psych.rb:99: warning: already initialized constant LIBYAML_VERSION
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] 
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] 
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] 
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] 
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] 
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] Gem files will remain installed in /home/deployer/apps/nthat1/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3 for inspection.
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] 
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] Results logged to  /home/deployer/apps/nthat1/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8- 3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/gem_make.out
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] 
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] 
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] continue.
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] 
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'` succeeds before bundling.
** [out :: 192.241.225.72] 
command finished in 174014ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
* executing "rm -rf /home/deployer/apps/nthat1/releases/20130911190337; true"
```

I logged into the server, and I did gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed libv8-3.16.14.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for libv8-3.16.14.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for libv8-3.16.14.3...
```

Again I did cap deploy I am getting the same error as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

In your deployment you are using a Ruby built with RVM. When you log into the box to manually install libv8, make sure you are using the same RVM based Ruby that you are using during deployment. Try this after logging in manually:

```
$ rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p448
$ gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'
```

Make sure that your ruby is coming from rvm:

```
$ which ruby
/home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby
```

Comment: I completely agree with this comment.